After updating 4.3 (Ctrl+Tab) shortcut key changed
In previous Blender version (4.2) I can easily switch between Graph Editor and Timeline by pressing (Ctrl+Tab), But in 4.3 version (Ctrl+Tab) has been changed to switching Graph Editor and Dope Sheet. Is this a bug or they have changed the controls?
Could someone help to change this in keymap. I don't use Dope sheet often.


Go to Preferences > Keymap and at the top switch to Key-Binding to search for ctrl tab.

In the results find Graph Editor Generic and expand the Context Set Enum.

Change Context Atrribute from area.type to area.ui_type

Change Value from DOPESHEET_EDITOR to TIMELINE


Original settings:

New settings:


Wow it worked THANKS alot bro
